# return FATAL ERROR when i repeat inflating. how do i do?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

this is the code impostazioni.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mie_impostazioni,
            container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

this is the code mie_impostazioni.xml

in linearlayout

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/pippo"
    android:name="com.example.andrea.myapplication.MyPreferenceFragment$PrefsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this is the PrefsFragment.java

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        }
    }
}
```

my problem is
when i call the seconth time inflating in IMPOSTAZIONI.java i return a FATAL ERROR, how do i do to solve it?

thanks a lot

this is my logcat when error appear

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3 a=-1}
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3 a=-1}
W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tab2Fragment{320be629 #0 id=0x7f0e0078 android:switcher:2131624056:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.andrea.myapplication, PID: 4600
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
         at com.example.andrea.myapplication.Impostazioni.onCreateView(Impostazioni.java:35)
         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #9: Duplicate id 0x7f0e0061, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.example.andrea.myapplication.MyPreferenceFragment$PrefsFragment
         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2120)
         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5367)
         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
         at com.example.andrea.myapplication.Impostazioni.onCreateView(Impostazioni.java:35) 
         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4600 SIG: 9
```

Comment: add the error stacktrace from logcat in your question

Answer (score 0):

i solve it

i added in IMPOSTAZIONI.java this code

```
    if (v==null)
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mie_impostazioni, container, false);

    else

    container.removeView(v);
    container.removeView((View) v.getParent());
```

bye